# Stacking Bootstrap Columns over each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using **Bootstrap** `v3` to develop my interface.
I use following snippet:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <h1>Hello...!</h1>
            <p>Para 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <h1>new div</h1>
            <p>Para 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when I decrease the size(width) of browser, the columns get smaller and smaller.
I want that, after a certain limit or min-width, the divs must stack over one another instead of getting smaller.

Comment: Can you be more specific about screen size? like on which screen you want it to break into stacks? like Laptop onwards, Tablet onward or mobile onwards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Follow this link for exact sizes of columns/grids for xs, and sm, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed
You are using a custom width functionality by using

```
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4" >
```

This gives custom width based on the device size. Instead for the columns to get stacked over by default just use this

```
   <div class="col-md-4">
```

instead of xs(xtra small) and sm(small size), use medium size as default, bootstrap will do the rest of your work. 
And another thing, there is also two different size for your columns(4 and 8), the view would be irregular.
And another thing, if you want to continue using custom sizes for columns instead of my method, remember this : xs-4 is different as sm-4

Comment: Awesome! I've been searching for this solution for awhile now.

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap-3 "Class prefix" represents as follows:

.col-xs - Extra small devices - Phones (<768px)

.col-sm - Small devices - Tablets (≥768px)

.col-md - Medium devices - Desktops (≥992px)

.col-lg - Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

In your coding (you are asking for desktop version i think so...) you have to remove `class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8"` and add `class="col-md-8 col-lg-8"`

the above code results, div over one another instead of getting smaller as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the non-stacking 'col-xs-*' grid class..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h1>Hello...!</h1>
    <p>Para 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <h1>new div</h1>
    <p>Para 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/92512