# Bootstrap different columns get together when xs screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive

I have five different columns:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>

</div>
```

All the content has `width: 100%`, so the size isn't bigger then expected and `padding: 0px`.

When the screen is XS (small device) one of the columns ("Vaccines/Chip") stays under the other, instead of passing to the next line which destroys the structure.

Images below to help:

[Big screen (lg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVLUI.png)

[Phone screen (xs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqsB9.png)

The code:

```
<div class="row" id="filters">

  <hr class="hr-between-animals" />

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px; padding:0">
    <b>Type of animal:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Dog
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Cat
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Rabbit
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Reptil
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Bird
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Fish
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Rat
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px; padding:0">
    <b>Size:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Small
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Medium
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Large
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px; padding:0">
    <b>Vaccines/Chip:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Vaccines
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Chip
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px; padding:0">
    <b>Gender:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Female
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" /> Male
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="margin-top:10px; padding: 0">
    <b>Age:</b>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#3D3D3D; background-color:transparent" />
    <div id="slider-range" style="border-color:#3D3D3D; border-          radius:5px; margin-top:10px"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The number of columns per row in bootstrap should equal 12. Your xs columns equals 30.

Comment: @j08691 I have put more than 12 columns into a row. It's helpful, for example, if the columns are dynamically generated by the server and you just want to throw a bunch of columns there. According to [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), "If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line." This suggests it's ok to put more than two columns since they will just wrap.

Comment: @Andrew - I didn't say it's forbidden, however it's not really the intended use to have the number of columns exceed 12.

Comment: @j08691 I know but you imply that you shouldn't do it. Like I said, it is useful if you want to dynamically append columns. You could add a div with the `clearfix` class to force columns into rows at different breakpoints.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, it's really helpful for dynamic websites, and I do this a lot of times, this was the first time this happened to me. I found a solution that isn't really correct in the column that is staying under the other set col-xs-7 instead of col-xs-6, but like i said, isn't the correct way. I never heard of clearfix, can you tell me in each div I should use it?

Comment: @SofiaChaves Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35662440/2518200) or this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6j1tybt/) where I put the clearfix in your code. Also, I think loan's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think another solution is to put `<div class="visible-xs clearfix"></div>` after every 12 columns to force the columns into rows at the XS size. Like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="visible-xs clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6"></div>
    <div class="visible-xs clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect! thank you, because I didn't want to destroy the design I was expecting! thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

Well, the total columns of a `row` should be `12`.
In *xs* mode it seems that you have `5 x col-xs-6` which is `30`. Try another combination so that the total is `12`.

Comment: so I should separate them with a new row, but out of mobile screen I want them to stay in a line, like it is in the LG picture, is there a way to do it?

Comment: You should use `sm`, and not `xs`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828435/stacking-bootstrap-columns-over-each-other

Comment: @loan But I think she wants xs because she wants it to stay on a line in mobile devices. If you use sm, it will break into separate lines.